# ReplyingKafkaTemplate - sendAndReceive serialisation issue

Tags: serialization, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am trying to use `ReplyingKafkaTemplate` to `sendAndReceive` message/response.

In the service that performs that I use a default instance of `ProducerFactory` and `ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory` that are provided to create a new instance of `ReplyingKafkaTemplate`, like this:

```
@Service
public class MyService {

  private final ReplyingKafkaTemplate<String, MyCommand, MyResult> kafkaTemplate;

  public MyService(ProducerFactory<String, MyCommand> pf,
                    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, MyResult> containerFactory) {
    var container = containerFactory.createContainer("results topic name");
    this.kafkaTemplate = new ReplyingKafkaTemplate<>(pf, container);
    kafkaTemplate.start();
  }

   //... other methods omitted as irrelevant...

  private Mono<MyResult> sendMessageAndWaitForResult(ProducerRecord<String, MyCommand> producerRecord) {
    var requestReplyFuture = kafkaTemplate.sendAndReceive(producerRecord);
    return Mono
      .fromFuture(requestReplyFuture.completable())
      .map(ConsumerRecord::value);
  }

  private ProducerRecord<String, MyCommand> createProducerRecord(Iterable<RecordHeader> recordHeaders, MyCommand myCommand) {
        return new ProducerRecord(
                "commands topic name",
                null,
                "some string id",
                myCommand,
                recordHeaders);
    }
}
```

`MyCommand` and `MyResult` are POJOs defined with the help of Lombok.

What I get as an error is:

```
KafkaException: Send failed; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Can't convert value of class MyCommand to class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer specified in value.serializer.
```

I know I didn't define a serializer but going through examples from `Kafka`, they only use `ReplyingKafkaTemplate<String, String, String>` examples and of course they need no serializer setup. But I do and can't find where and how to do it?

Thanks!

**EDIT 1**: Thanks to Garry Russell's tip I went the way to create a Bean for deserialiser, but somehow after getting some errors I managed to get it working this way:

```
public DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<String, MyCommand> producerFactory(
  KafkaProperties properties,
  AvroConverter avroConverter) {
        Map<String, Object> props = properties
  .buildProducerProperties();
        DefaultKafkaProducerFactory pf = 
  new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory(
    props,                                                                 
    new StringSerializer(),
    avroConverter.valueSerde().serializer());
        return pf;
}
```

The above was supposed to be a **@Bean** but when I did that, then I got the error mentioned in the comment below, The dependencies of some of the beans form a cycle.

So this `producerFactory` I pass when creating `ReplyingKafkaTemplate`.

What is puzzling is that I didn't have to create the same thing for deserialising the `MyResponse`?

`AvroConverter` is a class wrapping the creation of `SpecificAvroSerde`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are using Spring Boot; it configures a `StringSerializer` by default.

> KafkaException: Send failed; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Can't convert value of class MyCommand to class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer specified in value.serializer.

Since you are sending a POJO, not a String, you must use a different `Serializer` than the `StringSerializer`, such as the `JsonSerializer`.

See [Serialization, Deserialization, and Message Conversion](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#serdes).

With Spring Boot, you can specify the serializer as a property.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#application-properties.integration.spring.kafka.producer.value-serializer

```yaml
spring:
  kafka:
    producer:
      value-serializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer
```

Also see the samples

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/tree/main/samples

Comment: On the link you mentioned, (Serialization, Deserialization, and Message Conversion) there is maybe an error in an example

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#programmatic-construction

where it is possible to define the type for Deserializer as it is written but for Serializer, build works only if type is passed in the generic braces of JsonSerializer? Also returns are missing.

Also when I try to define my own producerFactory and consumerFactory Beans, I get:
The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle:

Comment: Thanks; yes; that documentation is wrong. I don't see why those beans could cause a cycle though. Please edit the question to show the error you are seeing.

Comment: I updated the post with a solution I manage to get working. Somehow I could not make it use a @Bean, which would be more elegant way I guess.